# Are UK visa vignette validity dates inclusive? Is arriving on the "valid until" date acceptable?

Tags: united-kingdom

Entry clearance vignettes for UK visas have their validity marked with two dates "Valid from" and "Valid until". Are both of those dates inclusive? Or is the "Valid until" date the first date that the vignette will be expired from?

Examples of UK entry clearance vignettes can be found here, I am asking about the Type D vignettes at the bottom of the document, which are what are currently issued: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/examples-of-uk-visa-vignettes

From a common English point-of-view, it is slightly ambiguous, but I would usually assume that both dates are included when listed and labelled as such. On the other hand, that would make the vignettes valid for a total of 31 or 91 days, when they are listed as 30 and 90 day vignettes. Using the example 30 day vignette in the link, including both dates gives 31 days total. This still makes sense if the first date is considered day 0, and each additional day is counted from there.

Would arriving on the "valid until" date still be acceptable?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What type of visa? A visit visa holder arriving on the ‘valid until’ date would have to leave by midnight on the same day, which would probably make little sense

Comment: My specific case is a Tier 5 Youth Mobility Scheme visa. Currently they are issuing 90 day vignettes, for a 2 year total period of stay. Sorry, I tried to word the question a little more generically, if arriving on the "valid until" date is acceptable at all.

Comment: I’m not aware of any reason why arriving on the last possible date would not be acceptable, although any travel delay could cause an issue if it meant you arrived after the visa expired. You’d also need to be sure you could collect your BRP within the given timeframe https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/collect